# How to set different currency in different cell depending on currency code

Tags: java, apache-poi, currency

I am trying to set different currencies in different cells with Apache POI.

I have JSON data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "shop1": [
            {
                "sku": "sku1",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sale": "100",
                "currency": "USD",
                "cost": 500
            },
            {
                "sku": "sku2",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sale": "100",
                "currency": "USD",
                "cost": 500
            }
        ],
        "shop2": [
            {
                "sku": "sku1",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sale": "100",
                "currency": "COP",
                "cost": 500
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want get the result like this (Excel data):

| shop | sku | quantity | sale | cost CNY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop1 | sku1 | 1 | $100.00 | ¥500.00 |
| shop1 | sku2 | 1 | $1,000,000.00 | ¥50,000,000.00 |
| shop2 | sku1 | 1 | COP 100.00 | ¥500.00 |

I want it to  show a different currency symbol according to the JSON `data.shop1[0].currency`, such as `CNY` show `¥` or `USD` show `$`

So I tried this:

```
XSSFCellStyle currency = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
currency.setDataFormat(7);
```

It fails, it only shows `¥`. It seems to parse the currency depending on where my system is located (China).

Then I tried:

```
String symbol = Currency.getInstance("CNY").getSymbol();
currency.setDataFormat(xssfWorkbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("{SYMBOL}#,#0.00".replace("{SYMBOL}", symbol)));
```

When I use `CNY`, it seem OK: I get `¥123.0`, but when I use `USD`, it fails because `Currency.getInstance("CNY").getSymbol();`  uses system default locale.

In Excel, I can set the symbol through right click a cell -> Format cells -> Number -> Currency -> Symbol (select).

What can I do to set the currency in Apache POI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting data formats like `£#,##0.00` always leads to user defined data formats. If you wants using `Excel` currency data formats, as done with **Format cells** -> **Number** -> **Currency** -> **Symbol** -> select, then you need th know what `Excel` stores in that case. Those currency data formats are stored using `$` followed by currency symbols in combination with [Windows Language Code Identifier (LCID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) in square brackets. For example:  `[$£-809]`. That is Pound Sterling `£` of United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland `LCID 809`.

To create such formats from `ISO` country codes, one would need a map which maps currency codes to `Excel` `LCID` currency codes. Unfortunately there is no such map available, as far as I know. So we need creating it from scratch. To do so, create a `Excel` `*.xlsx` having such currency values. Then unzip the `*.xlsx` (it is just a `ZIP` archive) and have a look into `/xl/styles.xml`. There you will find something like:

```
<numFmts count="6">
 <numFmt formatCode="[$$-409]#,##0.00" numFmtId="164"/>
 <numFmt formatCode="[$€-407]#,##0.00" numFmtId="165"/>
 <numFmt formatCode="[$¥-804]#,##0.00" numFmtId="166"/>
 <numFmt formatCode="[$₽-419]#,##0.00" numFmtId="167"/>
 <numFmt formatCode="[$£-809]#,##0.00" numFmtId="168"/>
 <numFmt formatCode="[$₺-41F]#,##0.00" numFmtId="169"/>
</numFmts>
```

Using that informations we can create following map:

```
static final Map<String, String> currencyCodesExcelLCID = new HashMap<>() {
 {
  put("USD", "[$\u0024-409]");  //[$$-409]
  put("CNY", "[$\u00A5-804]");  //[$¥-804]
  put("EUR", "[$\u20AC-407]");  //[$€-407]
  put("RUB", "[$\u20BD-419]");  //[$₽-419]
  put("GBP", "[$\u00A3-809]");  //[$£-809]
  put("TRY", "[$\u20BA-41F]");  //[$₺-41F]
 }
};
```

While creating the `Excel` cells we then can use that map to get needed `LCID` currency code for the cell's data format.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CreateExcelDifferentCurrencies {

 static final Map<String, String> currencyCodesExcelLCID = new HashMap<>() {
  {
   put("USD", "[$\u0024-409]");  //[$$-409]
   put("CNY", "[$\u00A5-804]");  //[$¥-804]
   put("EUR", "[$\u20AC-407]");  //[$€-407]
   put("RUB", "[$\u20BD-419]");  //[$₽-419]
   put("GBP", "[$\u00A3-809]");  //[$£-809]
   put("TRY", "[$\u20BA-41F]");  //[$₺-41F]
  }
 };

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Object[][] data = {
   {"Name", "Code", "Value"},
   {"US Dollar", "USD", 1234.56d},
   {"Euro (Germany)", "EUR", 1234.56d},
   {"Yuan Renminbi", "CNY", 1234.56d},
   {"Russian Ruble", "RUB", 1234.56d},
   {"Pound Sterling", "GBP", 1234.56d},
   {"Turkish Lira", "TRY", 1234.56d},
   {"Not available", "NA", 1234.56d}
  };

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDifferentCurrencies.xlsx";
  //HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDifferentCurrencies.xls";

  DataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
   Object[] dataRow = data[r];
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   String currencyCode = "";
   for (int c = 0; c < dataRow.length; c++) {   
    Object value = dataRow[c];
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (value instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)value);
     if (c == 1) currencyCode = (String)value;
    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)value);
     String symbolLCID = currencyCodesExcelLCID.getOrDefault(currencyCode, "");
     CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, dataFormat.getFormat(symbolLCID + "#,##0.00"));
    }
   }
  }

  for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution in your case is mapping `CODE -> SYMBOL`.
Just replace `Currency.getInstance("CNY").getSymbol();` with `codeSymbolMap.get("CNY")`.

The full list of currency codes and symbols are available i.e. [here](https://github.com/bengourley/currency-symbol-map/blob/master/map.js).

```java
private static Map<String, String> codeSymbolMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("AED", "د.إ");
        put("AFN", "؋");
        put("ALL", "L");
        put("AMD", "֏");
        put("ANG", "ƒ");
        put("AOA", "Kz");
        put("ARS", "$");
        put("AUD", "$");
        put("AWG", "ƒ");
        put("AZN", "₼");
        put("BAM", "KM");
        put("BBD", "$");
        put("BDT", "৳");
        put("BGN", "лв");
        put("BHD", ".د.ب");
        put("BIF", "FBu");
        put("BMD", "$");
        put("BND", "$");
        put("BOB", "$b");
        put("BOV", "BOV");
        put("BRL", "R$");
        put("BSD", "$");
        put("BTC", "₿");
        put("BTN", "Nu.");
        put("BWP", "P");
        put("BYN", "Br");
        put("BYR", "Br");
        put("BZD", "BZ$");
        put("CAD", "$");
        put("CDF", "FC");
        put("CHE", "CHE");
        put("CHF", "CHF");
        put("CHW", "CHW");
        put("CLF", "CLF");
        put("CLP", "$");
        put("CNY", "¥");
        put("COP", "$");
        put("COU", "COU");
        put("CRC", "₡");
        put("CUC", "$");
        put("CUP", "₱");
        put("CVE", "$");
        put("CZK", "Kč");
        put("DJF", "Fdj");
        put("DKK", "kr");
        put("DOP", "RD$");
        put("DZD", "دج");
        put("EEK", "kr");
        put("EGP", "£");
        put("ERN", "Nfk");
        put("ETB", "Br");
        put("ETH", "Ξ");
        put("EUR", "€");
        put("FJD", "$");
        put("FKP", "£");
        put("GBP", "£");
        put("GEL", "₾");
        put("GGP", "£");
        put("GHC", "₵");
        put("GHS", "GH₵");
        put("GIP", "£");
        put("GMD", "D");
        put("GNF", "FG");
        put("GTQ", "Q");
        put("GYD", "$");
        put("HKD", "$");
        put("HNL", "L");
        put("HRK", "kn");
        put("HTG", "G");
        put("HUF", "Ft");
        put("IDR", "Rp");
        put("ILS", "₪");
        put("IMP", "£");
        put("INR", "₹");
        put("IQD", "ع.د");
        put("IRR", "﷼");
        put("ISK", "kr");
        put("JEP", "£");
        put("JMD", "J$");
        put("JOD", "JD");
        put("JPY", "¥");
        put("KES", "KSh");
        put("KGS", "лв");
        put("KHR", "៛");
        put("KMF", "CF");
        put("KPW", "₩");
        put("KRW", "₩");
        put("KWD", "KD");
        put("KYD", "$");
        put("KZT", "₸");
        put("LAK", "₭");
        put("LBP", "£");
        put("LKR", "₨");
        put("LRD", "$");
        put("LSL", "M");
        put("LTC", "Ł");
        put("LTL", "Lt");
        put("LVL", "Ls");
        put("LYD", "LD");
        put("MAD", "MAD");
        put("MDL", "lei");
        put("MGA", "Ar");
        put("MKD", "ден");
        put("MMK", "K");
        put("MNT", "₮");
        put("MOP", "MOP$");
        put("MRO", "UM");
        put("MRU", "UM");
        put("MUR", "₨");
        put("MVR", "Rf");
        put("MWK", "MK");
        put("MXN", "$");
        put("MXV", "MXV");
        put("MYR", "RM");
        put("MZN", "MT");
        put("NAD", "$");
        put("NGN", "₦");
        put("NIO", "C$");
        put("NOK", "kr");
        put("NPR", "₨");
        put("NZD", "$");
        put("OMR", "﷼");
        put("PAB", "B/.");
        put("PEN", "S/.");
        put("PGK", "K");
        put("PHP", "₱");
        put("PKR", "₨");
        put("PLN", "zł");
        put("PYG", "Gs");
        put("QAR", "﷼");
        put("RMB", "￥");
        put("RON", "lei");
        put("RSD", "Дин.");
        put("RUB", "₽");
        put("RWF", "R₣");
        put("SAR", "﷼");
        put("SBD", "$");
        put("SCR", "₨");
        put("SDG", "ج.س.");
        put("SEK", "kr");
        put("SGD", "S$");
        put("SHP", "£");
        put("SLL", "Le");
        put("SOS", "S");
        put("SRD", "$");
        put("SSP", "£");
        put("STD", "Db");
        put("STN", "Db");
        put("SVC", "$");
        put("SYP", "£");
        put("SZL", "E");
        put("THB", "฿");
        put("TJS", "SM");
        put("TMT", "T");
        put("TND", "د.ت");
        put("TOP", "T$");
        put("TRL", "₤");
        put("TRY", "₺");
        put("TTD", "TT$");
        put("TVD", "$");
        put("TWD", "NT$");
        put("TZS", "TSh");
        put("UAH", "₴");
        put("UGX", "USh");
        put("USD", "$");
        put("UYI", "UYI");
        put("UYU", "$U");
        put("UYW", "UYW");
        put("UZS", "лв");
        put("VEF", "Bs");
        put("VES", "Bs.S");
        put("VND", "₫");
        put("VUV", "VT");
        put("WST", "WS$");
        put("XAF", "FCFA");
        put("XBT", "Ƀ");
        put("XCD", "$");
        put("XOF", "CFA");
        put("XPF", "₣");
        put("XSU", "Sucre");
        put("XUA", "XUA");
        put("YER", "﷼");
        put("ZAR", "R");
        put("ZMW", "ZK");
        put("ZWD", "Z$");
        put("ZWL", "$");
    }
};
```